# Ошибка при повторном создании папки в планировщике задач Delphi (CoTaskScheduler)

Tags: delphi, исключения, планировщик-задач

Необходимо создать папку в планировщике задач имея переменную `ts` типа `TaskSchd.ITaskService`.

```
ts := CoTaskScheduler.Create();
ts.Connect('', '', '', '');
tf := ts.GetFolder('\').CreateFolder('test_F', null);
```

Первый запуск программы создаёт папку без проблем. Но, при повторном запуске, система сообщает об ошибке "Данная папка уже существует". Пытался через `try except` решать проблему, но не получилось (Сначала появлялось окно с ошибкой, а потом запускался обработчик).

Как обработать это исключение, чтобы не появлялось уведомление системы об ошибке?

P.S. Другие методы работы с планировщиком не подходят, только через приведённые в коде объекты.

Comment: MSDN показывает немного другие сигнатуры методов у этих интерфейсов. `GetFolder` и `CreateFolder` должны возвращать HRESULT с кодом ошибки. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381838(v=vs.85).aspx Это у вас какие-то обертки  к этим интерфейсам?

Comment: @kot-da-vinci Нет, это не обёртки, а стандартные интерфейсы для работы с планировщиком через COM соединение (Microsoft Windows TaskScheduler API v.2.0, находиться в taskschd.dll). На счёт возвращаемого значение - это объект `ITaskFolder`. В его полях я не нашел ничего связанного с ошибками, только `Path`, `Name`, и ещё некоторые функции и процедуры. Вариант решения к которому я пришел (он не особо мне нравиться) - получить список всех папок в директории при помощи `ts.GetFolder('\').GetFolders(0);` , а потом через обычный `if then` проверять наличие создаваемой папки.

Comment: Я попробовал импортировать эти интерфейсы в Delphi и интерфейсы получились как у вас, а не как на MSDN. Очень странно, никогда с таким не сталкивался. А в `try..except` вы `CreateFolder` пробовали заворачивать или что-то другое?

Comment: @ kot-da-vinci . Да, именно `CreateFolder`.  При этом сначала выскакивало окно с ошибкой, а потом срабатывал обработчик. Хотелось бы как-то избавиться от этого всплывающего окна и оставить только обработку исключения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам должна помочь установка режима отображения системных ошибок [SetThreadErrorMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd553630(v=vs.85).aspx). Она запрещает системе отображать диалоговые окна с ошибками и система вместо этого отправляет ошибку вызывающему потоку.

Если в вашей версии Delphi эта функция не объявлена, объявить ее можно так:

```
function SetThreadErrorMode(uNewMode: DWORD; var uOldMode: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall; external kernel32 name 'SetThreadErrorMode';
```

В моем случае, это помогло избавиться от сообщения типа "Отсутствует носитель", когда я пытался получить объем логического диска, который находился на картридере, в момент отсутствия карты памяти.

```
uses
  Windows;
var
  OldErrorMode: Cardinal;
begin
  SetThreadErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS, OldErrorMode);
  try
    // действия, которые могут привести к появлению нежелательного диалога
  finally
    SetThreadErrorMode(OldErrorMode, OldErrorMode);
  end;
end;
```